# UUPS proxy with the Brownie framework

Tags: solidity, contract-design, openzeppelin, brownie, proxy-contracts

I am trying to implement a UUPS proxy using the OpenZeppelin `UUPSUpgradeable` abstract contract. I actually succeeded to do so but I think that there may be a better way than the one I found.

In other frameworks like Truffle or Hardhat, the implementation of proxies is an embedded functionality of the framework. In Brownie it is not the case (or i just didn't find this functionality), so to solve my problem I wrote my own proxy contract using OpenZeppelin `ERC1967Upgrade` proxy as an inspiration. Here is the code of my contracts and the python code testing it:

1. The proxy contract

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/proxy/Proxy.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/StorageSlot.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Address.sol";

contract TokenPoolFactoryProxy is Proxy {
    /// @notice From Openzeppelin ERC1967Upgrade abstract contract
    constructor(address _logic) payable {
        _setImplementation(_logic);
    }

    /// Returns the implementation contract address
    /// @return address
    function _implementation() internal view virtual override returns (address) {
        return _getImplementation();
    }

    /// Storage slot with the address of the current implementation.
    /// This is the keccak-256 hash of "eip1967.proxy.implementation" subtracted by 1, and is
    /// validated in the constructor.
    /// @notice From Openzeppelin ERC1967Upgrade abstract contract
    /// @return bytes32
    function _getImplementationSlot() private view returns (bytes32){
        // Equivalent to:
        // bytes32(uint256(keccak256("eip1967.proxy.implementation")) - 1)
        return 0x360894a13ba1a3210667c828492db98dca3e2076cc3735a920a3ca505d382bbc;
    }

    /// Returns the current implementation address.
    /// @notice From Openzeppelin ERC1967Upgrade abstract contract
    /// @return address
    function _getImplementation() private view returns (address) {
        return StorageSlot.getAddressSlot(_getImplementationSlot()).value;
    }

    /// Stores a new address in the EIP1967 implementation slot.
    /// @notice From Openzeppelin ERC1967Upgrade abstract contract
    function _setImplementation(address newImplementation) private {
        require(Address.isContract(newImplementation), "ERC1967: new implementation is not a contract");
        StorageSlot.getAddressSlot(_getImplementationSlot()).value = newImplementation;
    }
}
```

2. The implementation contract

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/proxy/utils/UUPSUpgradeable.sol";

contract TokenPoolFactory is UUPSUpgradeable {

    /// Checks the authorizations before upgrading the implementation
    function _authorizeUpgrade(address newImplementation) internal virtual override {
        // TODO
    }

    function testProxy() external view onlyProxy returns (uint8) {
        return 42;
    }
}
```

3. The python test

```py
from brownie import Contract, TokenPoolFactory, TokenPoolFactoryProxy
from brownie.exceptions import VirtualMachineError
from scripts.common.AccountManager import AccountManager

account_manager = AccountManager()

def test_deploy_through_proxy():
    # GIVEN
    account = account_manager.get_account()
    expected_test_value = 42
    non_proxy_call_failed = False

    # WHEN
    pool_factory = TokenPoolFactory.deploy({"from": account})
    proxy = TokenPoolFactoryProxy.deploy(
        pool_factory.address,
        {"from": account}
    )
    proxified_factory = Contract.from_abi(
        "Proxified factory",
        proxy.address,
        pool_factory.abi
    )
    test_proxy = proxified_factory.testProxy()
    try:
        pool_factory.testProxy()
    # THEN
    except VirtualMachineError as e:
        non_proxy_call_failed = True
        assert "Function must be called through delegatecall" in str(e)

    assert expected_test_value == test_proxy
    assert non_proxy_call_failed
```

As I said everything seems to work as expected but it feels weird to have to write my own proxy instead of using something from OpenZeppelin.

Comment: One more thing that is off to me is that you are forced to use constructors in this upgradable contract while they are usually avoiding them.